# Select query with MAX(ad_number) issue

Tags: mysql, select, max

```
$r = ca_mysql_query("SELECT MAX(ad_number) FROM `myTable` WHERE  `user` = {$user_id} ");

$max = $r[0]['ad_number'];
echo $max;
```

It should print max ad_number but its not returning any value
wheares, 
if  i try query removing MAX(ad_number) its returnig field data from array.

```
$r = ca_mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `myTable` WHERE  `user` = {$user_id} ");

$max = $r[0]['ad_number'];
```

is returning value for the given records

whats is wrong ?

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: The column is not named "ad_number", it is named "MAX(ad_number)". If you want to have a different name, use AS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an alias for you column:

```
SELECT MAX(ad_number) as max_ad_number FROM myTable WHERE  user = {$user_id}
```

Then do this:

```
$max = $r[0]['max_ad_number']; echo $max;
```

See documentation from w3schools [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
$r = ca_mysql_query("SELECT MAX(ad_number) AS AD_NUMBER FROM myTable WHERE user = {$user_id} ");

$max = $r[0]['AD_NUMBER']; 
echo $max;
```

Comment: You need to put an ALIAS for the result, and use it as identifier too